# how can I customise the error message for request from wrong paths in aws api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I use api gateway and custom authorizer.
when the path is defined in resources, everything is fine. 
when there was a typo in the url/paths, I get this error below.
Can I customize this error message? I'd like to tell the caller that they are requesting the wrong paths

```
{
  "message": "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization="
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do this. docs have entire section titled [Set up Gateway Responses to Customize Error Responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html) specially dedicated to this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I should define the responseTemplate for MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I should define the responseTemplates for MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN.

*The gateway response for a missing authentication token error, including the cases when the client attempts to invoke an unsupported API method or resource. If the response type is unspecified, this response defaults to the DEFAULT_4XX type.*

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses": {
    "MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN": {
      "responseParameters": {
        "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
      },
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json": "{\"message\":$context.error.messageString,\"hint\":\"The HTTP method or resources may not be supported. "}"
      }
    }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html